# Preventing expansion of : in batch file for loop

Tags: batch-file, team-foundation-server, scripting, expansion

Trying to build a cmdline tool for reviewing TFS changesets.  Currently I have this:

```
rem I know there's redundancy here, but don't care for now
set /A curr=%1
set /A prev=%curr%
set /A prev-=1

for /f "tokens=2" %g in ('tf changeset /noprompt %curr%') do tf diff /noprompt /format:unified /version:C%prev%~C%curr% %g
```

Which gives the following result:

```
g:\>tfdiffchangeset.bat 2458
currunified was unexpected at this time.
```

I'm not even sure why the : is turning into "curr", but if I remove /format, I get the same thing happening in /version.

Secondarily, if I just replace the :'s with spaces assuming I'll deal with that later, I get this error

```
g:\>tfdiffchangeset.bat 2458
The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter
substitution is invalid: %~C%curr% %g

For valid formats type CALL /? or FOR /?
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

Is it time to write tfdiffchangeset.pl?

Final Version:

```
@ECHO off

set /A CURR=%1
rem Note - just using one changeset less doesn't necessarily work, because branches also use the same changeset numbers
set /A PREV=%CURR%-1

echo diffs for %CURR%

tf changeset /noprompt %CURR%

for /f "tokens=2" %%g in ('tf changeset /noprompt %CURR%') do tf diff /noprompt /format:unified /version:"C%PREV%~C%CURR%" %%g
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
for /f "tokens=2" %%g in ('tf changeset /noprompt %curr%') do tf diff /noprompt /format:unified /version:C%prev%~C%curr% %%g
```

From `HELP FOR`:

> To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify %%variable instead
>   of %variable.  Variable names are case sensitive, so %i is different
>   from %I.

Comment: Seems you got rid of the issue with the :, now there's the ~ issue.
<br/>
 g:\eddynet\EddynetDependent>tfdiffchangeset 2464
<br/>
The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter
substitution is invalid: %~C%curr% %g
<br/>
For valid formats type CALL /? or FOR /?
<br/>
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Comment: Actually, I'll give you the answer, since you made me look at the help, which told me to use upper case to deal with the ~